# Pass value from webtest Context Parameter to loadtest Context Parameter

Tags: performance, visual-studio

I am running a load test in Visual Studio and I have written a custom extraction rule to get some data from the screen and store it in a Context Parameter in the webtest. What I am trying to do now is to take that value and copy it into a similar Context Parameter that is attached to the loadtest, so that I can use a LoadTestPlugIn to output the data from all the tests. Getting data from the loadtest to webtest seems to be easy, just not sure how to pass it back the other way.

Comment: Hello, have you found a way?  I've got the same situation.  Thanks.